# why my code are removing duplicates python

Tags: python, dictionary

why my dict ain't accept duplicate keys or values?

```py
def meeting():
  
  s = "Alexis:Wahl;John:Bell;Victoria:Schwarz;Abba:Dorny;Grace:Meta;Ann:Arno;Madison:STAN;Alex:Cornwell;Lewis:Kern;Megan:Stan;Alex:Korn"
  
  b = dict([a.strip().replace(';', ',') for a in el.split(':')] for el in s.split(';'))

  b = {k.upper(): v.upper() for k, v in b.items()}

  lista = [(v, k) for k, v in b.items()]
  c = ''.join(sorted('({}, {})'.format(i[0], i[1]) for i in lista))
  
  
  print(b)
  print(c)
            
meeting()
```

as we can see, we got the name Alex Cornwell and Alex Korn, the output only gets the last instance of Alex, and don't return both of them.

i've tried everything but i'm stuck on this.

thank you if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a dict. That's just the way it is.

Comment: thank you, i didn't knew that.  i'll use a different approach for it

Comment: thank you a lot sr. i change dict to list and it works. :)

Answer (score 1):

By defition, a dictionary can't have duplicate keys. In this case, since you're not doing any special treatment when the key already exists, it gets overwritten with the new value.

**Values can be duplicated, it's the keys that must be different**. For instance, if you used `"Alexis:Wahl;John:Wahl"`, the output would be `(WAHL, ALEXIS)(WAHL, JOHN)`.

When I said about special treatment, an example of what you could do would be to instead create a list with values, and, if that key already exists, simply add the new value to that list but then you'd have a dict with name, and inside that name, a list of surnames, and I don't know if that works for you.

Or, if you won't really need to access the dictionary by keys at all, you could convert to tuples directly, skipping the step of converting to a dictionary first.

I'll just give an example of the last option:

```py
def meeting():
    s = "Alexis:Wahl;John:Bell;Victoria:Schwarz;Abba:Dorny;Grace:Meta;Ann:Arno;Madison:STAN;Alex:Cornwell;Lewis:Kern;Megan:Stan;Alex:Korn"
    lista = [tuple((x.upper().strip() for x in el.split(":"))) for el in s.split(';')]

    # notice that in this version I'm reversing name and surname only
    # when passing the parameters to format
    c = ''.join(sorted('({}, {})'.format(surname, name) for name, surname in lista))
    print(lista)
    print(c)

meeting()
```

Just an extra detail: I'd make `meeting()` receive `s` as a parameter and populate it outside, mainly because it's good practice. But there's also immediate advantages, for instance, you can test easier with different inputs:

```py
def meeting(s):
    lista = [tuple((x.upper().strip() for x in el.split(":"))) for el in s.split(';')]

    # notice that in this version I'm reversing name and surname only
    # when passing the parameters to format
    c = ''.join(sorted('({}, {})'.format(surname, name) for name, surname in lista))
    print(lista)
    print(c)

s = "Alexis:Wahl;John:Bell;Victoria:Schwarz;Abba:Dorny;Grace:Meta;Ann:Arno;Madison:STAN;Alex:Cornwell;Lewis:Kern;Megan:Stan;Alex:Korn"
meeting(s)

# other tests below
s2 = "Alexis:Wahl;John:Wahl"
meeting(s2)
```

---

<sub>You'll notice I've removed the `replace` part. Since you're already using `split(";")`, there will never be `;` to replace for `,`. Maybe you meant to replace `,` with `;`?</sub>